# How to implement bezier function in react native animation?

Tags: react-native

i want to implement  a bezier curve animation which is provided by easing in react native but the docs are not very clear about how to implement it. please  need your suggestion

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here on this repository you can see some examples of the use of react-native-easing:
[react-native-easing](https://github.com/thisXY/react-native-easing)

Here's the file on the repository:

```js
import { Easing } from 'react-native';

export default {
  step0: Easing.step0,
  step1: Easing.step1,
  linear: Easing.linear,
  ease: Easing.ease,
  quad: Easing.quad,
  cubic: Easing.cubic,
  poly: Easing.poly,
  sin: Easing.sin,
  circle: Easing.circle,
  exp: Easing.exp,
  elastic: Easing.elastic,
  back: Easing.back,
  bounce: Easing.bounce,
  bezier: Easing.bezier,
  in: Easing.in,
  out: Easing.out,
  inOut: Easing.inOut,

  easeIn: Easing.bezier(0.42, 0, 1, 1),
  easeOut: Easing.bezier(0, 0, 0.58, 1),
  easeInOut: Easing.bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1),

  easeInCubic: Easing.bezier(0.55, 0.055, 0.675, 0.19),
  easeOutCubic: Easing.bezier(0.215, 0.61, 0.355, 1.0),
  easeInOutCubic: Easing.bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1.0),

  easeInCirc: Easing.bezier(0.6, 0.04, 0.98, 0.335),
  easeOutCirc: Easing.bezier(0.075, 0.82, 0.165, 1.0),
  easeInOutCirc: Easing.bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86),

  easeInExpo: Easing.bezier(0.95, 0.05, 0.795, 0.035),
  easeOutExpo: Easing.bezier(0.19, 1.0, 0.22, 1.0),
  easeInOutExpo: Easing.bezier(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0),

  easeInQuad: Easing.bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53),
  easeOutQuad: Easing.bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94),
  easeInOutQuad: Easing.bezier(0.455, 0.03, 0.515, 0.955),

  easeInQuart: Easing.bezier(0.895, 0.03, 0.685, 0.22),
  easeOutQuart: Easing.bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1.0),
  easeInOutQuart: Easing.bezier(0.77, 0.0, 0.175, 1.0),

  easeInQuint: Easing.bezier(0.755, 0.05, 0.855, 0.06),
  easeOutQuint: Easing.bezier(0.23, 1.0, 0.32, 1.0),
  easeInOutQuint: Easing.bezier(0.86, 0.0, 0.07, 1.0),

  easeInSine: Easing.bezier(0.47, 0.0, 0.745, 0.715),
  easeOutSine: Easing.bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1.0),
  easeInOutSine: Easing.bezier(0.445, 0.05, 0.55, 0.95),

  easeInBack: Easing.bezier(0.6, -0.28, 0.735, 0.045),
  easeOutBack: Easing.bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275),
  easeInOutBack: Easing.bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55),

  easeInElastic: Easing.out(Easing.elastic(2)),
  easeInElasticCustom: (bounciness = 2) => Easing.out(Easing.elastic(bounciness)),
  easeOutElastic: Easing.in(Easing.elastic(2)),
  easeOutElasticCustom: (bounciness = 2) => Easing.in(Easing.elastic(bounciness)),
  easeInOutElastic: Easing.inOut(Easing.out(Easing.elastic(2))),
  easeInOutElasticCustom: (bounciness = 2) => Easing.inOut(Easing.out(Easing.elastic(bounciness))),

  easeInBounce: Easing.out(Easing.bounce),
  easeOutBounce: Easing.in(Easing.bounce),
  easeInOutBounce: Easing.inOut(Easing.out(Easing.bounce)),
};
```

And here's what each function generates:

[image]